# Why would the link not open in a new window?

Tags: html

If I click on the `<a>` tag in a browser the link won't work. If I right-click and select open in a new tab, it works.

```html
<div class="step-text-box">
  <p class="step-number">HD 4-Post</p>
  <h3 class="heading-tertiary">
    New Heavy-Duty Pit Racks
  </h3>
  <p class="step-description">
    Hunter's new P490HD and P491HD heavy-duty alignment pit racks offer easy installation for the shop owner and easy access for the technicians. Accomodte a wide variety of vehicles with two length options. They are the perfect solution for extended vehicles
    such as motor coaches, whose length and low clearance often prevent them from accessing a traditional rack.
    <a class="link" href="https://www.hunter.com/" target="_blank">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `target="_blank"` has security issues. Maybe the browser is preventing the link from being clicked for that reason. Try changing the a tag to: `<a class="link" href="https://www.hunter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Learn more</a>`

Comment: If you look up "tab nabbing" you can read about the security issues when you don't include `rel="noopener noreferrer"` in `a` tags with `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Is the problem consistent across different browsers? Which browsers have you tried? Do you have any javascript that could be the problem?

Comment: Javascript was doing it.

Comment: allLinks.forEach(function (link) {
  link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = link.getAttribute("href");

    // Scroll back to top
    if (href === "#")
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });

Comment: // Scroll to other links
    if (href !== "#" && href.startsWith("#")) {
      const sectionEl = document.querySelector(href);
      sectionEl.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }

    // Close mobile naviagtion
    if (link.classList.contains("main-nav-link"))
      headerEl.classList.toggle("nav-open");
  });
});

Comment: how can I change this so they both work?

Comment: In this case, it seems JavaScript caused the issue. Incidentally, here in the stack snippet, I get "Blocked opening [url] in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my comment "conditional for preventDefault" you can use this `if/else` statement to conditionally apply `e.preventDefault` as long as the `a` tag doesn't have the attribute and value of `target="_blank"`.

```
allLinks.forEach(function (link) { 
        link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            // conditional for preventDefault
            if (link.hasAttribute("target") === false) {
                    e.preventDefault();
            } else {
            if (link.getAttribute("target") !== "_blank") {
                    e.preventDefault(); 
            }
         }
```

Did this work for you?

Comment: I have another issue with the javascript that I need your help with.

Comment: You helped me get the absolute URL’s working, I've added some mailto and tel urls. and those aren't working. How can this code be changed so that absolute URL’s,  mailto and tel urls work?